# lightning-tabset picking the incorrect variable to set active-tab-value

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-tabset, connected-callback, lifecycle

I have a `lightning-tabset` with three tabs, problem is the active-tab-value of the lightning tabset, I wish to set it's value based on a boolean value that Im setting in `connectedCallback` but it picks the global variable value. I cannot understand why this is happening

Here is the code

```html
<template>
    <lightning-tabset active-tab-value = {activetabVal}>
        <lightning-tab value = 'one' label="Item One">
            One Content !
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Item Two" value = 'two' title="2nd tab extended title">
            Two Content !
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Item Three" value = 'three'>
            Three Content !
        </lightning-tab>
    </lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

JS

```js
export default class TabsetBasic extends LightningElement {

    boolVal;   // this controls the active-tab-value behaviour

    connectedCallback(){
        this.cv();
    }
    cv (){
        this.boolVal = true;  // not controlling the active-tab-value behaviour
    }
      activetabVal=  (this.boolVal)? 'two': 'three';

}
```

the class level variable `boolVal` if I switch the boolean values between true and false the default tab functionality works, but if I set it in `connectedCallback` and keep switching the boolean values it doesnt work, the `activeTabVal` is picking the global variable value. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is because you assigned the value to `activetabVal`, its value is evaluate at time of declaration based on initial value of `boolVal`.

From connected callback, when you change `boolVal` value, it does not re-evaluates `activetabVal`.

For this to work, you could change the `activetabVal` property to a [getter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/js_props_getters_setters).

```
get activetabVal() {
    return (this.boolVal) ? 'two': 'three';
}
```

Comment: I have a question. What if there is a renderedCallback that keeps resetting the boolVal value whenever its value changes as it is reactive, how do we handle this scenario then?

Comment: Ideally that should also work, do you see it not behave as expected? If not then share an example